# Hbase Testing Utility dependency issue with ZKTestingUtility

Tags: scala, hbase

Trying to use HbaseTestingUtility in Scala 2.12.8 and I get

```
Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseZKTestingUtility not found - continuing with a stub.
      new HBaseTestingUtility()
```

sbt imports

```
val hbaseVersion = "2.1.3"
val hadoopVersion = "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % hbaseVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % hbaseVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop-compat" % hbaseVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop2-compat" % hbaseVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop-compat" % hbaseVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop2-compat" % hbaseVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-testing-util" % hbaseVersion
)
```